# Why in a pivot the "include new items in manual filter" option is grey out when source is a powerpivot?

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot

I have several pivots which source is a powerpivot, but the "include new items in manual filter" option in all my pivots are grey out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? Ensure you didn't save the file as "compatible" version. 
If you have a file created/saved as older versions you need to save the file in one of the new file formats. The feature is not enabled with “Excel 2003 compatible” files for instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer me. Mi version is Office professional Plus 2013. and I have saved the file several times even I have created a new file with the same Data and it doesn't fix it. But I have noticed that if the field is in the column section I can use this functionality.